# Android Library Project casting error on extended Application class

Tags: android

I am whitelabeling my app.  To do this, I've:

- Converted my Android Application Project into an Android Library Project.  We'll call it `com.mylibraryproject.app`.
- Created a new project.  We'll call it `com.example.testproject`.
- Added my Android Library Project as a library of my new Android Application Project.
- Copied the manifest from my Android Library Project into the manifest for my new Android Application Project and referenced the Activities appropriately.

Example:

```
<activity
      android:name="com.mylibraryproject.app.activity.MyActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

However, I'm having a crash when my new Android Application Project runs.

The library project contains a class, we'll call it `MyApp`, that extends `Application`.  All over this project, there are references to `(MyApp)getApplicationContext()`.

When the above line is hit, the below exception is thrown. How do I avoid this?

**Update:**

Here is the full `onResume()` method and log cat:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();
    if (app.getUserId() == -1 && !app.getUserConnected() && app.loadLastUser()) {
        updateDisplay();
    } else if (!mBack && app.getUserConnected()) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception

```
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.testproject/com.mylibraryproject.app.activity.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.mylibraryproject.app.activity.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:277)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
02-21 13:13:11.169: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  ... 12 more
```

Line 277 is this line:

```
MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application` an `ApplicationContext` aren't the same thing. You need to cast a `getApplication()` result instead

Of course, casting just says that *"I know this object is an xyz so let me treat it as that"* ... it doesn't actually transmute one object into another type

**Edit:**

Change your onResume like below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();
    if (app.getUserId() == -1 && !app.getUserConnected() && app.loadLastUser()) {
        updateDisplay();
    } else if (!mBack && app.getUserConnected()) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
}

<application android:name="com.mypackage.MyApp"
    ....>
```

Comment: I've updated the offending line from `(MyApp)getApplicationContext()` to `(MyApp)getApplication()` and I am still receiving the same exception.

Comment: then it's time to post your stack trace. What you've posted is a symptom, the whole stack will show the cause (probably even says 'caused by'). Also provide your 'onResume' method as the current exception implies that's where your issue lies

Comment: Update your code like in my edit. If you still get an exception replace the one in your question with it and tell us what line number protected void onResume() { is on

Comment: It's blowing up on `MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();` with the same exception.  Also, just to note, I **am** performing a clean and rebuilding both the Android Library Project and, subsequently, the Android Application Project.

Comment: Wait, did you add the application class to the manifest like my new edit?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that.  No I did not.  However, won't this give my whitelabel application the same identifier as my library, meaning I could not install the whitelabel and the library project (were it converted back into a application project) on the same device?  Or, to put it another way, would it prevent me from creating 2 whitelabels?

Comment: Making the manifest change has allowed the application to run.  It also appears I can have both versions on the same device.